# How to get the values of dictionary python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the below python dictionary stored as `dictPython`

```
{
    "paging": {"count": 10, "start": 0, "links": []},
    "elements": [
        {
            "organizationalTarget~": {
                "vanityName": "vv",
                "localizedName": "ViV",
                "name": {
                    "localized": {"en_US": "ViV"},
                    "preferredLocale": {"country": "US", "language": "en"},
                },
                "primaryOrganizationType": "NONE",
                "locations": [],
                "id": 109,
            },
            "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",

        },
    ],
}
```

I need to get the values of `vanityName, localizedName` and also the values from `name->localized` and `name->preferredLocale`.

I tried `dictPython.keys()` and it returned `dict_keys(['paging', 'elements'])`.

Also I tried `dictPython.values()` and it returned me what is inside of the parenthesis({}).

I need to get `[vv, ViV, ViV, US, en]`

Comment: I'm seeing five questions like this per day. Is there a canonical for accessing nested collections?

Comment: @timgeb found something right now. I didn't know they are called nested collections. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```py
dic = {
    "paging": {"count": 10, "start": 0, "links": []},
    "elements": [
        {
            "organizationalTarget~": {
                "vanityName": "vv",
                "localizedName": "ViV",
                "name": {
                    "localized": {"en_US": "ViV"},
                    "preferredLocale": {"country": "US", "language": "en"},
                },
                "primaryOrganizationType": "NONE",
                "locations": [],
                "id": 109,
            },
            "role": "ADMINISTRATOR",
        },
    ],
}
base = dic["elements"][0]["organizationalTarget~"]
c = base["name"]["localized"]
d = base["name"]["preferredLocale"]
output = [base["vanityName"], base["localizedName"]]
output.extend([c[key] for key in c])
output.extend([d[key] for key in d])

print(output)
```

outputs:

```py
['vv', 'ViV', 'ViV', 'US', 'en']
```

Comment: Yep. That works for me. I didn't know how to iterate the nested collection.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this in a form of answer, so I can get to explain it better without the comments characters limit

- a `dict` in python is an efficient key/value structure or data type
  for example `dict_ = {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}` to fetch `key1` we can do it in 2 different ways

  1. `dict_.get(key1)` this returns the value of the key in this case `val1`, this method has its advantage, that if the key1 is wrong or not found it returns `None` so no exceptions are raised. You can do `dict_.get(key1, 'returning this string if the key is not found')`
  2. `dict_['key1']` doing the same `.get(...)` but will raise a `KeyError` if the key is not found

So to answer your question after this introduction,
a `dict` can be thought of as nested dictionaries and/or objects inside of one another
to get your values you can do the following

```
# Fetch base dictionary to make code more readable
base_dict = dict_["elements"][0]["organizationalTarget~"]
# fetch name_dict following the same approach as above code
name_dict = base_dict["name"]
localized_dict = name_dict["localized"]
preferred_locale_dict = name_dict ["preferredLocale"]
```

so now we fetch all of the wanted data in their corresponding locations from your given dictionary, now to print the results, we can do the following

```
results_arr = []
for key1, key2 in zip(localized_dict, preferredLocale_dict):
    results_arr.append(localized_dict.get(key1))
    results_arr.append(preferred_locale_dict.get(key2))

print(results_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
[[x['organizationalTarget~']['vanityName'],
  x['organizationalTarget~']['localizedName'],
  x['organizationalTarget~']['name']['localized']['en_US'],
  x['organizationalTarget~']['name']['preferredLocale']['country'],
  x['organizationalTarget~']['name']['preferredLocale']['language'],
 ] for x in s['elements']]
```